# What is the equivalent, in LotusScript, for Ruby's inspect. (list class members/etc)?

Tags: oop, lotusscript

I need to know how I can list the object/class members of a lotusscript object, as text, for debugging purposes. I don't know 'what' the return from an object is.

In this case I am using the ls.SNAPPS.JSONReader class to read some JSON, and need to make a nested call.

```vb
Set jsonReader = New JSONReader
Set vResults = jsonReader.parse(result)
Modifiers = vResults.GetItemValue("_embedded").GetItemValue("modifiers").items
ForAll modifier In Modifiers
    Modifiers2 = modifier.GetItemValue("_embedded").GetItemValue("price_levels").items
    ForAll modifiers3 In Modifiers2 
        ^-- here is where it explodes, type mismatch. 
    End Forall
End Forall
```

I have verified the json has the _embedded [] modifiers [] _embedded [] price_levels[] structure in it.

Comment: What do you see in Modifiers2 when you run this in the debugger? And what do you expect to see?

Comment: I tracked down my issue, it was not checking isEmpty before the forall.. on some menu items there were no price_levels entries. My question would have been helped by knowing _of_ the lotusscript debugger and not relying on console logging to do debugging. I still would like a log-to-console inspector command, though this seems to be not the 'domino way'.